# Is it ok to claim that an integral of an odd function in a symmetric interval is 0?

Tags: integration

For instance,

$$\int_{-1}^1 \sin x(7-\cos^4x) \,dx = 0$$

Since sinx is odd, and the interval is symmetrical?

Comment: Yes, this is perfectly valid.

Comment: Yes, as long as it's convergent

Comment: So you mean $$\int_{-1}^1\sin(x)(7-\cos^4(x))dx$$?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Funnily enough it isn't relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is perfectly legal. In the case, if $f(x)$ is odd, then from $-a$ to $a$, the integral vanishes. This can be proven by splitting up the integral

$$\begin{align*}\int\limits_{-a}^{a}\mathrm dx\, f(x) &=\int\limits_{0}^{a}\mathrm dx\, f(x)+\int\limits_{-a}^0\mathrm dx\,f(x)\\ & =\int\limits_{0}^a\mathrm dx\, f(x)-\int\limits_{0}^a\mathrm dx\, f(x)\\ & =0\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 1):

Basically yes. Note however that integrals like 
$$\int_{-1}^1 \frac1{x} \mathrm{d} x \quad\text{or}\quad
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x}{1 + x^2} \mathrm{d}x$$
cannot be said to be zero because they fail to converge.

Comment: Yes, it is true for riemann definition of integral, but in the lebegue definition, you can in a way ignore the singular point and calculate the integral. Here again, it would be zero. There is some discussion on this here 'https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3048916/584828' if you're interested.

Comment: @Mustang AFAIK these functions are not Lebesgue integrable since the integral of their positive/negative parts is $\pm \infty$

Comment: Sorry, I'm not too clear about the details myself(I am not familiar with lebegue theory), this is basically what my prof. told me when I asked him the same question(for $\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{1}{x}$ he said we could take $x=0$ as the principal value and work it out). This is also roughly what one guy answered in the link. Hopefully someone more experienced can shed some light here?

Comment: I say - don't confuse things. If the integral exists, it's zero. A principal value is a way to stretch that "exists" to something broader, but it's not part of the standard definition. As for Lebesgue integrals - no. Principal values are not a thing in the Lebesgue theory.